# Transition not working in my responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, transition

This is the css code(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ581.png)
This is the HTML Code(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwhBn.png)

Actually transition in .main is not working

Comment: Don't post code as **image** except you want answer as image.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, do not just dump everything on external platforms.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you will have to add the code to your question. Images don't count, take the time to proper copy paste the relevant part of your code please!

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of confused on what you mean by "not working", but I can show you how to code a transition:

```
p{ color: blue; 
transition: 1s; }

p:hover{ color: red; 
transition: 1s; }
```

Comment: not working mean the navbar is not coming smoothly